# How can I select a Random Number within a group and make that selected number unique among other groups?

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel

1) 9 groups of 4 numbers (integers)

2) Each integer value less that 10

3) Each number is unique within the group

4) Multiple Groups can have same number(s) Group A 1,3,7,5 - Group B 2, 5, 8, 9- etc.

Want to randomly select a number within group of 4
But each group must have a unique resulting number between the groups.
(i.e. no group can have the same resulting number)

[image: Partial Problem Solution]

Here is a copy of excel - [download here][2]

Comment: You didn't attach your code. What part of the code you have written gives you a problem?

Comment: didn't see attachment option on the post ...

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't have attachments; questions should contain the relevant code as text within the question itself.

Comment: Dear @DJ your download link is not visible/accessible.. would you mind edit the "download here" part.

Comment: also.. the "3" selected by your formula in B10 seems to have no problem, why change it to 7?